# excanvas drawimage doesn't work on IE8

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-8, html5-canvas, excanvas

Hi I have managed to make excanvas work in IE8 for simple examples however I couldn't make the following canvas example which contain drawimage work at IE8. Does anyone have any experience with excanvas and drawimage.
Thanks for your help...

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');`
```

`canvas.setAttribute("width", 300);

canvas.setAttribute("height", 300);

foo.appendChild(canvas);

canvas= G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.save();

                ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

                ctx.translate( canvas.width/2 , canvas.height/2 );

                ctx.drawImage( image, -165, -160 );

                ctx.rotate( 100 * Math.PI / 180);

                ctx.drawImage( image2, -13, -121.5 );

                ctx.restore();`

```
image1.src = 'img.png';
image2.src = 'img2.png';
```

Comment: Does it work in a browser-native canvas? Maybe you're not waiting for your images to load?

Comment: I have another version which works I have just changed here variable foo and create a canvas element.

Answer (score 1):

Use a test case to isolate drawImage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Overflow Test</title>
<style>
body {
  text-align: center
}
</style>
<!--[if IE]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
  var img = document.images[0];
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 8);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 50, 50);
  img.style.display = 'none';
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">

<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

**References**

[Explorer Canvas test cases: drawimage.html](https://github.com/jonessieka/explorercanvas/blob/master/testcases/drawimage.html)